# How are std::move template parameters deduced?

Tags: c++, templates, c++11

Suppose we have:

```
foo(A&& a);
```

if you do

```
A a;
foo(a);
```

it won't compile and complain cannot bind a lvalue to A&&. that's perfectly fine.

However, given the signature of std::move,

```
template<class T> typename remove_reference<T>::type&& std::move(T&& a);
```

Looks like it takes a rvalue reference, just as in foo, why the following code complies?

```
A a;
std::move(a);
```

isn't `a` is a lvalue?

furthur, it is said the compile will instantiate:

```
typename remove_reference<A&>::type&& std::move(A& && a);
```

I don't understand why it is not:

```
typename remove_reference<A>::type&& std::move(A && a);
```

it looks to me `a` is of type `A`, not `A&`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Despite what others have said, the standard only talks about rvalue references.

The key to how this works for std::move is an explicit special rule in the rules for template argument deduction:

> [...] If [the declared function parameter type] is an rvalue reference
>   to a cv-unqualified template parameter and the argument is an lvalue,
>   the type “lvalue reference to A” is used in place of A for type
>   deduction.[...]

The other part are the rules for reference collapsing, which say that

> If [...] a type template-parameter [...] denotes a type TR that is a reference to
>   a type T, an attempt to create the type “lvalue reference to cv TR”
>   creates the type “lvalue reference to T”, while an attempt to create
>   the type “rvalue reference to cv TR” creates the type TR.

Now in `template<class T> typename remove_reference<T>::type&& std::move(T&& a);` the function parameter a matches above rule ("rvalue reference to cv-unqualified template parameter"), so the deduced type will be an lvalue reference to the argument type, if the argument is an lvalue. In your case that leads to T = A&.

Substituting that into the declaration of move yields

```
remove_reference<A&>::type&& std::move<A&>(A& && a);
```

Using the definition of remove_reference and the reference collapsing rule (rvalue reference to TR => TR), makes this:

```
A&& std::move<A&>(A& a);
```

Scott Meyer's *universal reference* concept, as put forward in other answers, is a helpful way to remember this surprising effect of the combination of the rules for type deduction and of reference collapsing: rvalue references to a deduced type may end up being lvalue references (if the type may be deduced to be a lvalue reference). But there are no *universal references* int the standard. As Scott Meyers says: it is a lie - but a lie that is more helpful than the truth...

Note that std::forward is a different twist on this theme: it uses an extra indirection to prevent argument deduction (so that the type must be given explicitly), but also uses reference collapsing to forward lvalues as lvalues and rvalues as rvalues.

Answer (score 10):

Nope `move` doesn't take an rvalue-reference, it takes what has been dubbed a *universal reference* by the community. Template parameters being type-deduced behave according to the rules of *reference collapsing*. This means:

- if `T` is `K`, then `T&&` will simply be `K&&`;
- if `T` is `K&`, then `T&&` will collapse to `K&`;
- if `T` is `K&&`, then `T&&` will collapse to `T&&`.

It's like a logical-AND of the `&` and the `&&` where `&` is 0 and `&&` is 1:

```
      &    &&
   |-----------|
&  |  &  |  &  |
   |-----|-----|
&& |  &  | &&  |
   |-----------|
```

And that's how `move` works for both rvalues and lvalues.

Examples:

```
template<typename T>
void f(T&&);

f<int>   // T is int;   plugging int into T makes int&& which is just int&&
f<int&>  // T is int&;  plugging int& into T is int& && which collapse to int&
f<int&&> // T is int&&; plugging int&& into T is int&& && which collapse to int&&
```

Note that reference collapsing only happens with template parameters; you can't directly type `int&& &&` and expect it to compile. Of course, you don't specify types manually like that. Those are just to show what references collapse to.

So you'd really call it like this:

```
int i;

f(i); // T is int&;  int& && collapses to int&
f(4); // T is int&&; int&& && collapses to int&&
```

Reference collapsing is also the reason why `move` doesn't return a `T&&`: the references would collapse if `T` were an lvalue reference and make `move` just return an lvalue reference. You do `remove_reference` to get to a non-reference type so that the `&&` will really mean "rvalue-reference".

You can learn more here: http://isocpp.org/blog/2012/11/universal-references-in-c11-scott-meyers

Answer (score 3):

The syntactic form `T&&` *in the context of type deduction* (which includes *template argument deduction*, but for instance also the deduction of the type of a variable declared as `auto`) does *not* indicate an rvalue reference, but rather what Scott Meyers calls a [*universal reference*]. Please notice, that only the very particular *syntactic form* `T&&` denotes a universal reference, while other, similar forms are not regarded as such. For instance:

```
template<typename T> 
void foo(T&& t); <-- T&& is a universal reference

template<typename T> 
void foo(T const&& t); <-- T const&& is NOT a universal reference

template<typename T> 
void foo(S<T>&& t); <-- S<T>&& is NOT a universal reference

template<typename T> 
struct S { void foo(T&& t); }; <-- T&& is NOT a universal reference
```

Universal references can bind both to lvalues and to rvalues. If an lvalue of type `A` is bound, then `T` is deduced to be `A&` and the type of the argument resolves into `A&` (lvalue reference) due to the rule of *reference collapsing* (`A& &&` becomes `A&`). If an rvalue of type `A` is bound, then `T` is deduced to be `A` and the type of the argument resolves into `A&&` (rvalue reference).

[**Note**: *Reference collapsing rule might seem complicated, but they are actually quite easy: to quote Stephan T. Lavavej, "lvalue references are contagious", meaning that when the forms `T&& &`, `T& &`, or `T& &&` get instantiated, they always resolve into `T&` - only the form `T&& &&` is resolved into `T&&`*]

This is why the `std::move` function template will be instantiated as follows when the argument is an **lvalue** (`T` is deduced to be `T&`):

```
typename remove_reference<A&>::type&& std::move(A& && a);
```

while it will be instantiated as follows when the argument is an **rvalue** (`T` is deduced to be `A`)

```
typename remove_reference<A>::type&& std::move(A&& a);
```